# Strange space in WebStorm/PhpStorm 2022 between tags

Tags: reactjs, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, tsx

I'm using React and writing tags in a tsx file. When I use Reformat code, spaces appear instead of newlines. Tell me how to fix this and what could be causing this?

[image]

Comment: What did you try? All jetbrains products allow you to modify the formatting at a very granular level under `Settings > Editor > Code Style > {your language}`

Comment: @possum no, it's not help for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was very strange for me. But I figured out what was going on. I have a version of PhpStorm from 2020, which I updated every year until 2022.3. I simply reset the TypeScript settings and reconfigured them again and everything worked as it should. Therefore, as a solution for those who have the same situation: just reset the TypeScript settings and configure them again, do not go into details.

I’ll assume on my own that this is some kind of outdated setting that was hidden from the interface and it directly affects this behavior. Since I can’t reset it from the interface, only a full reset helps.

Answer (score 1):

JSX tags are considered 'inline' when formatting, this can't be configured unfortunately. I can only suggest adding line breaks manually, having the **Keep line breaks in text** enabled to preserve them on re-formatting. Related youtrack ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-37966

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try the line break option under

> keep when reformatting

which is inside

> Editor > code style > javascript > Wrapping and Braces